# Firefox can not start up

Tags: firefox, desktop-environments

I am facing this error when I start firefox

> Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or
>   inaccessible.

I just installed ubuntu so I do not know what's wrong with it. I am using chrome now. I must use sudo firefox to start firefox which is very troublesome.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
firefox -profilemanager
```

When the window opens, delete the profile, and create a new one.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's not working.  Here is the error    : Error: Access was denied while trying to open files in your profile directory.

Comment: Try `sudo firefox -profilemanager`, and see what happens.

Comment: This command is ok, but after delete profile and add profile, it still prompt the error