# Firefox doesn't start

Tags: firefox

I am on ubuntu 14.04, and when I try to launch firefox 38.0 it won't start up and I get this message:

```
Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible.
```

This is what I get when I follow this question; [Firefox can not start up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/314908/firefox-can-not-start-up)

```
firefox -profilemanager

(process:3381): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Error: Access was denied while trying to open files in your profile directory.
```

I have / on one partition and /home on another, wich was transfered and mounted after instalation, not during it. Could it be a permission problem? If so, how could I fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Click the `Places menu` on the top right of the screen and select `Home Folder`.

A File Browser window will appear.

Click the `View menu` and select `Show Hidden Files` if it isn't already checked.

Double click the folder marked `.mozilla`.

Double click the folder marked `firefox`.

Delete the `profiles.ini` file.

When you start `Firefox`, a `new profile` will be created.

Comment: Or just change the reference location in the profiles.ini file to the path/name of the profile folder you want to use. Of course first back up both profiles.ini and profile folder(s) just to be safe.